# MySQL update error message

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to store in MySQL the last date and hour that a user accessed his account. When I log in I get the following error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '16:06:21 WHERE email = 'something@host.com'' at line 1

```
$query="UPDATE users SET last_visit=$last_visit WHERE email = '$email'";
mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
```

last_visit is of datetime type.

```
$last_visit = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
```

I know that MySQL is depreciated. I'll use MySQLi.

Let me know if I need to edit my question before downrating. Thanks!

Comment: you need quotes around `$last_visit`

Comment: it is best practice to always put `'` around values to prevent errors of spaces in your inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the quotes `'` since `last_visit` column is a `DATETIME` :

```
$query="UPDATE users SET last_visit='$last_visit' WHERE email = '$email'";
```

Comment: True story. It's crazy how we miss the simplest things sometimes. Thank you very much! I'll accept your answer as soon as I can.

Comment: Better keep your variables out of your string. like this: `$query = "Update...". $last_visit ." WHERE email = '". $email ."'";` of use string formats.

Comment: @SporeDev this is not an accident but a direct consequence of totally **wrong approach**

Comment: @Tikkes true... but there's an even better alternative : prepared statements

Comment: Yes indeed but as he says he's using mysql, this is a good solution. Of course, as he also said, mysqli would be prefered.

Comment: @Tikkes **there is absolutely nothing good in this approach**. Neither in general nor for the question asked.

Comment: Do explain then? Why would you ever keep a variable in a string?